# How many rows affected in a second, while SQL Server bulk inserting?

Tags: sql-server, rows, bulkinsert

This question was asked to me in an interview. After the interview, I searched in Google and I couldn't get any clues. Does anybody knows about it?

How can I determine the *exact* or *approximate* inserted rows in a second while doing SQL Server Bulk Insert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the elapsed time. Divide by the number of rows. The value would be the rate.

The number of rows that are inserted is going to vary on many factors, such as:

- The width of the row
- The size of the file
- The performance of the network/file system
- The performance of the server running the database
- Other processes running on the server/database
- And no doubt a zillion other factors.

Hence, there is no exact numeric answer.